# How to not display labels in "Patch Clusters Example"?

Tags: netlogo

Is it possible to not display labels in "Patch Clusters Example". However, I would like to keep value of plabel for each road in order to count number of black roads between red patches. Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to display labels, you can get rid of the whole `show-clusters` procedure.

Regarding the second part of your question, you don't need labels "to count number of black roads between red patches".

The "Patch Clusters Example" works by assigning each patch to a cluster identified by a "leader patch", using the `cluster` patch variable.

If you want to know how many patches are in a cluster, just take one of the patches from that cluster and count the number of patches that are in the same cluster.

In your case, that would be something along the lines of:

```
let target-patch one-of patches with [ pcolor = black ] ; a random road patch
ask target-patch [
  show count patches with [ cluster = [ cluster ] of myself ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks very much Seth and Nicolas ! In fact, I would rather like to know how many clusters are in the Netlogo world. With plabel:`let cluster-number length ( sort remove "" ( remove-duplicates ( [plabel] of patches ) ) )` or without plabel: `let cluster-number length ( remove "" ( remove-duplicates ( [cluster] of patches ) ) ) - 1`. But if it is not possible to use plabel without displaying it, how can I work, for example, with the cluster that has the number 6 (i.e. `patches with [plabel = 6]`). In the code, "cluster" has the format (patch 0 11). I prefer a numerical value. Thanks.

Comment: `length remove nobody remove-duplicates ([cluster] of patches)` should give you the number of clusters. If you _really_ want to keep a numerical value for the clusters, you could simply modify `show-cluster` to assign this number to a new patch variable instead of `plabel`. If you don't like the "patch leader" approach (I know I don't) you could try to approach the whole problem in a different way, but that's a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove these lines:

```
ask p
[ ask patches with [cluster = [cluster] of myself]
  [ set plabel counter ] ]
```